# Regex syntax for single alpha character in string of digits

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new to regex syntax and am looking for a way to match the following criteria:

1. String has 1 alpha character and the rest are digits
2. String starts with at least 1 digit but no more than 3
3. Following character is a single alpha character (upper or lower case a-Z)
4. Followed by 4 to 6 digits

Example valid data:

```
1A1111
1A11111
1A111111
11A1111
11A11111
11A111111
111A1111
111A11111
111A111111
```

---

Most examples I'm finding are matching 1 or more of a value so I'm struggling with how to match specific number of characters and what place they can be found in.

For example:

Matching 1 or more digits at the start of the string: `@"^\d"`

or Making sure the string has at least one Alpha character:

```
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(tokenString, @"(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

But this doesn't tell it that there can be only 1 alpha character.

Comment: 1 or more digits at the start of the string. Use the OR (ie. | ) modifier in your Regex. I think that's what you are missing, if not let me [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work

```
^\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]\d{4,6}$
```

breakdown:

```
^        - match at beginning
\d{1,3}  - one to three digits
[a-zA-Z] - one letter a-z or A-Z
\d{4,6}  - followed by between 4 and 6 digits
$        - and that's end of the string...
```

Comment: You guys make it look so easy :-)  Thanks for the break down explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this one.

```
^\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]\d{4,6}$
```

Answer (score 3):

The following pattern should do what you are asking for:

```
^\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z]\d{4,6}$
```

Well, since you are using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, you can get away with just:

```
^\d{1,3}[a-z]\d{4,6}$
```

For more info on what you can do with Regular Expressions, go here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html